# How can I deploy React App to GoDaddy domain

Tags: reactjs

I am new to using Reactjs, I just finished a project for a client and I need to upload it to a domain on GoDaddy. I ran `npm run build` already and I now have a `build` folder. I'm just not sure how to proceed. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: if its a host, you can upload your build into it and config your hataccess file to run it successfully

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain name is not enough, you need to host your application somewhere. You can use [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) or [zeit](https://zeit.co/) (both have free tiers) to deploy your application. After deploying the app you can link your domain to navigate to the application.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options, but heres a simple one to get you up and running quick. Upload to github repo and link your github account to netlify. In the netlify account deploy your project which will show at a random netlify domain. Change the nameservers in netlify to point to your godaddy domain and your app is live.